# Why can't brew find a specific known formula?

Tags: homebrew, bazel

I'm trying to install bazel on my mac (10.11.5).

I can see that it is available through brew:
http://braumeister.org/formula/bazel

But when I run "brew install bazel", I get this:

```
Error: No available formula for bazel 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
```

Why is this?

Comment: Try `brew search baz` maybe....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my case, Homebrew was already up-to-date after running `brew update` and I still received the same error messages as the OP when trying to install xdebug:

```
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
$ brew install php70-xdebug
Error: No available formula with the name "php70-xdebug"
```

Using Mark's suggestion from the comments on OP solved the problem:

```
$ brew search xdebug
homebrew/php/xdebug-osx    homebrew/php/php70-xdebug
```

So now, running `$ brew install homebrew/php/php70-xdebug`, Homebrew found and installed the package.

Comment: Thanks for posting, missed Mark's comment (as always)

Answer (score 8):

You should update your brews, because it is indeed available. Run

```
brew update
brew install bazel
```

and then it should work.